# How to test a method that save an object to the database with hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, testing, mocking

I wrote CRUD app (Notebook), and now I'm learning how to test my code.
I wrote some tests using mocks, but in this case Idk how to test for example my method -> addNote.
I searched a few pages with testing CRUD but I have not found similar code to this.

This is my Controller:

```
@Controller
public class NoteController {


private NoteService noteService;

@Autowired
public NoteController(NoteService noteService) {
    this.noteService = noteService;
}

@GetMapping("/notebook")
public String getNotebook(Model model)
{
    model.addAttribute("notes",noteService.getNotes());
    model.addAttribute("newNote",new Note());
    return "main-view";
}

@PostMapping("/notebook/add-note")
public String addNote(Model model, @ModelAttribute Note note)
{
    if(note.getTitle()==null || note.getTitle() == null)
    {
        model.addAttribute("errorMessage","You have to fill in the title and text, to save the note");
    }
    else {
        noteService.saveNote(note.getTitle(), note.getText());
    }
    return "redirect:/notebook";
}

@GetMapping("/notebook/{id}")
public String getNoteById(Model model, @PathVariable Long id)
{
    Note note = null;
    try {
        note = noteService.findNoteById(id);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        model.addAttribute("errorMessage","Note not found");
    }
    model.addAttribute("note", note);
    return "show-note";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/notebook/{id}/edit", method = {RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})
public String editNoteById(Model model, @PathVariable Long id,@ModelAttribute Note updatedNode)
{
    if(updatedNode!=null)
    {
        noteService.update(updatedNode);
    }
    Note note = null;
    try {
        note = noteService.findNoteById(id);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        model.addAttribute("errorMessage","Note not found");
    }
    model.addAttribute("edit",true);
    model.addAttribute("note", note);

    return "show-note";
}

@PostMapping("/notebook/{id}/delete")
public String deleteNote(@PathVariable Long id)
{
    noteService.deleteNote(id);
    return "redirect:/notebook";
}
```

And the only thing I was able to test with the addNote method was redirection:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ApiTest {

@Autowired
MockMvc mockMvc;

@Test
public void addNote() throws Exception {

    mockMvc.perform(post("/notebook/add-note")
            .param("title","mmtitle")
            .param("text", "mmtext"))
            .andExpect(redirectedUrl("/notebook"));

}
```

As you can see, I also use param, which creates a new object in my database, but I don't know how to check it using test. Can you tell me how can I do it, or link me any source, where I can learn testing with mocks?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you would only test code that you have written. It is safe to assume that the database driver works.

If you want to make sure that the record did indeed end up in the database, have Spring autowire the repository for you.

```
@Autowired
private NoteRepository noteRepository;
```

This requires that a database for testing is configured. Most Spring Boot configured system come with either H2 or HSQL, lightwight in-memory databases.

You can then query the database using the repository, and make sure you can load the saved entry from there.

Answer (score 0):

you can indeed test with an in-memory database, but if you prefer the mock-based approach you can test the behavior of objects involved, assuming that the underlying Hibernate code works :-)

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class ControllerTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @MockBean
  private NoteRepository noteRepository;

  @Test
  public void addNote() throws Exception {

    String json = "{" +
            "\"id\":1," +
            "\"name\":\"my note\"" +
            "}";

    this.mockMvc.perform(post("/notebook/add-note")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(json)
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

    verify(noteRepository, times(1)).save(isA(Note.class));

}
```

Using the NoteRepository mock you can verify which methods are called and how many times.

You will need to exclude DataSourceAutoConfiguration to turn off the automated datasource initialisation (which you dont want if you test without a running database).